# What's the difference between iterator syntax in range-based loops for STL containers

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator

Although I'm more than knowledgeable about C and OOP in Java, I'm starting to dive into C++ and its particularities. I've read all the basic things about C++, but I'm still confused with some C++11-specific things, both syntax- and performance-wise. On of such things are container iterators, which I have found implemented in a myriad of syntax forms (e.g. [range-based loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)).

I was wondering which of these are completely equivalent, why would one want to use one or another and what are the effects in performance.

**a) `auto` vs explicit declaration:**

Is the `auto` always supported? Aside from code readability issues, why would a programmer prefer the explicit declaration?

```
list<int>::const_iterator i = myIntList.begin();    /* Option a1 */
auto i = myIntList.begin();                         /* Option a2 */

for(auto i : myIntList) { ... }                     /* Option a3 */
for(int i : myIntList) { ... }                      /* Option a4 */
```

**b) Compact form vs extended loop form**

```
list<int> l = {1, 2, 3, ...};
for(auto i : l) { ... }                             /* Option b1 */
for(auto i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); ++i) { ... }  /* Option b2 */
```

**c) Constant, non-constant / Access type**

Why/when would one prefer to have a reference or a constant in the loop body?

```
/* Constant/non-constant: */
for(list<int>iterator i = l.begin(); ...) { ... }   /* Option c1 */
for(list<int>const_iterator i = l.begin(); ...) { } /* Option c2 */

for(const int& i : list) { ... }                    /* Option c3 */
for(int& i : list) { ... }                          /* Option c4 */

/* Access by reference/by value: */
for(auto&& i : list) { ... }                        /* Option c5 */
for(auto i : list) { ... }                          /* Option c6 */
```

**d) Loop's exit condition:**

```
/* Option d1: end is defined within the start condition or outside the loop. */
for(auto i = l.begin(), end = l.end(); i != end; ++i) { ... }

/* Option d2: end is defined in the continue condition. */
for(auto i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); ++i) { ... }
```

Perhaps most of them are identical, and perhaps the choice of one option or another only makes sense for a given loop body, but I wonder what's the purpose of allowing so many possible ways of programming the same behaviour.

Comment: Are you speaking specifically about standard containers?

Comment: I'd separate constant/non-constant from reference/value cases.

Comment: Also iterating over elements vs iterators. I think you are asking too many things here.

Comment: `I wonder what's the purpose of allowing so many possible ways of programming the same behaviour.` because the language has to remain compatible with older versions while adding improved syntax. it's that simple. everything else you asked has been discussed to death elsewhere. flagging as too broad.

Comment: @underscore_d Actually, most of the "possible ways" actually do different stuff.

Comment: @juanchopanza true, I meant that range-`for` is often a shorthand for various things that can be specified using explicitly iterator-based syntax, probably oversimplified though. I still maintain that this 'question' is actually many questions, all of which are amply answered elsewhere, whether that's on SO or simply in a good C++ reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the forms are alternatives, and each has advantages and disadvantages compared with others.

1)  Explicit declaration of loop variables is preferred when you want a type different than `auto` might deduce.   It is also mandatory if it is necessary to maintain compatibility with C++ implementations predating C++11 (yes, there are practical real-world cases where that is necessary - there is a cost in changing compiler, just as there is a cost in maintaining an old one).

2)   The "compact" form (more correctly, a range based loop) is unsuitable if the requirement is anything other than iterating sequentially over all elements in a range.   For example, if looping over every second element, if the loop body resizes the container for some reason (which invalidates iterators).

3)   A `const` qualifier signals an intent is that the loop will not change elements of the container.   This can be very useful for getting the compiler to diagnose issues where the loop (potentially) makes an unintended change of elements.  e.g. calling a non-`const` member.   Without using the `const` qualifier, there are numerous circumstances where such problems are bugs that are very difficult to track down.

4)   Defining the end condition within the start condition results in undefined behaviour if the loop body resizes the container in any way (since that invalidates the iterators).   Recalculating the end condition on every loop iteration can prevent such issues.

The purpose of having so many distinct ways of writing loops is programmer convenience.   Depending on what the programmer is attempting, different techniques may be appropriate.

The trade-off is that sometimes it is difficult to decide on the most "suitable" form of loop.

Answer (score 4):

> Is the auto always supported?

Only since C++11, but so are range based loops, so if you can rely on one, then you should be allowed to rely on another.

---

> Aside from code readability issues, why would a programmer prefer the explicit declaration?

You can do an implicit conversion to another type with explicit type.

---

> Compact form vs extended loop form

You can do more with explicit use of iterators (what you call "extended"), than you can with a range based loop (what you call "compact"). But, if you simply want to iterate the range of elements once, then range based loop has much simpler syntax. This is why it was introduced to the language.

---

> Why/when would one prefer to have a reference [...] in the loop body?

When one cannot copy, or wants to avoid copying of the iterated elements.

> Why/when would one prefer to have a [...] a constant in the loop body?

When one only has const access to the range, or one wants to express that they do not intend to modify the object.

---

> Loop's exit condition

If the end pointer is invalidated within the loop, then only `d2` is correct.

If the end iterator is invariant, then `d1` can be slightly more efficient due to bringing a function call out of the loop.

If the compiler can see the definition of `T::end()`, then it may optimize by transforming `d2` as written, into `d1`.

In any case, the overhead of a single function call is often negligible, unless the loop body itself is trivial.

---

> I wonder what's the purpose of allowing so many possible ways of programming the same behaviour.

It is true that all loop structures could be implemented using `goto`.

So, why would c++ allow any other loop structures? `for`, `while` etc were introduced to make the program easier to understand, more readable. OK, then why not get rid of `goto`, when `for` is easier to understand? That is because `for` cannot do all that `goto` can. `goto` is more general.

Same reasoning holds for this new range based loop. It is easier to reason about than the more general loop structures, and therefore a useful addition. But the general structures still have their place for uses that are not possible with the range based loop. Besides, removing the general `for` structure would break backwards compatibility of the language, which would be undesirable.

Answer (score 2):

Range based `for(:)` loops are, unusually in C++, defined in terms of `for(;;)` loops.  Prior to C++17 it was basically identical to option **d1**, with the note that the iterator variables are invisible in client code.

Note that range based iterate over elements, not over valid iterators.  Youmcan make a ranged based over iterators, but it requires some glue code.

Post C++17 range based `for(:)` was modified so that it permits `end` to have a different type than `begin`.  This was useful for the sentinal technique, but is not that important a difference at this point.

`auto` always works like it does.  Barring expression template fancyness, it always works in ways one can easily understand.  Using it can make types a touch harder to work out, but sometimes you do not care, and sometimes you are just needlessly repeating the type.  Not using it can lead to surprising type mismatches if you screw up.

A reference is an alias.  A value is a copy.  If ypu want to iterate over copies, you can.  If you want to iterate over aliases to the content of the container, you can.

Similarly, you can have a `const` or non-`const` view of the contents of the container.  You get to pick, depending on what you need or want.

Biasing towards `const` and values can make code a touch easier to decode for programmers and compilers.  However, needless copies of complex structures can be expensive, and `const` can inhibit move and implicit move and other mutation-for-efficiency tricks.

If you cache `end` (d1 vs d2) it can sometimes be slightly faster.  But usually not noticable, and it is noise.  In theory a non-cached end could work better if the container changes, but changing the container while iterating is usually madness and requires modification of the advance clause as well as the termination.  The `for(:)` loop caches end, because the noise argument is gone.

`auto&&` deduces a forwarding reference for the variable: it can be an lvalue reference, or an rvalue reference-to-temporary.  It means "I don't care, don't copy anything but let me work with it".  Reference lifetime extension will usually make dangling references not a problem, so long as the source of the data you are binding does not screw up.

Another big thing you are missing is non-member `begin`.  That permits access to C-style arrays as if they where ranges, and if done in the right way lets you easily add range support to third party range-likes so `for(:)` works on them too.

Answer (score 1):

> [a] Is the `auto` always supported? Aside from code readability issues, why would a programmer prefer the explicit declaration?

almost always yes, and they would prefer explicit typing if they wanted to perform a conversion from the RHS type to a non-identical type on the LHS... or just don't like implicit stuff.

> b) Compact form vs extended loop form

Is there a question here? The difference is, of course, that you don't have to dereference an iterator in range-`for`.

If your algorithm requires you to do stuff with iterators and/or operations that invalidate them (e.g. insertion, erasure), then you need iterators, so use the 'old'/'manual' syntax.

But if you don't, then range-`for` avoids the hassle of having to dereference the iterator by doing that for you.

> [c] Why/when would one prefer to have a reference or a constant in the loop body?

The choice between a reference or constant, like anywhere else - notably including the almost identical choice for function arguments - depends on

- whether you want to alter the element, hence `&`
- even if not, whether it would be expensive to copy by value into the loop variable on each iteration, hence `const &`

> d) Loop's exit condition:

The 2nd variant caches the `end()` iterator, which is

- possibly faster, but check compiled output to verify
- no use if any operation within the loop invalidates the `end()` iterator

Answer (score 1):

**a) `auto` vs explicit declaration:**

`auto` is always supported because all types are known at compile time.

The most important reason to declare the type explicitly is code readability, as it makes it easier to figure out the type when reading the code later. In addition, explicitly declaring the type allows you to convert the item to another type if there is an implicit conversion.

**b) Compact form vs extended loop form:**

Both are completely equivalent. You should use the compact form when possible.

**c) Constant, non-constant / Access type:**

The reason why you would want to use `const` references instead of mutable references is *const correctness*, a protection mechanism that keeps you from mutating objects when you shouldn't. In particular, if you only have a `const` reference to the container itself, you can only use `const` references, or copies of the values, in the loop body.

A common piece of advice is to use `const` whenever possible, at least with method parameters. If a method receives a `const` reference to an object, you can rest assured that the method won't mutate the object (unless there is a `const_cast` somewhere).

Accessing the items by value is the shortest option, works even with `const` containers, and doesn't have any performance penalty if the item type is a small scalar type (`bool`, `int`, `double` etc.) It's what you'd want to do by default.

You'll need to access the items by reference if they are of a noncopyable type or if you want to mutate them. In addition, if they're of a large class type, accessing the items by reference is faster.

**d) Loop's exit condition:**

Option `d2` only calls `l.end()` once, which is slightly faster in theory. However, in practice `end()` is an extremely fast method. Option `d1` is almost always preferred because it's shorter.

**The purpose of allowing many ways**

Consider loops, for example. C++ was evolved from C and it supports C-like loops for the purpose of being familiar for C programmers and backwards compatible with existing C code.

The range-based for loop is just syntactic sugar over the old looping method. There is no reason to disallow the old looping syntax: besides, disallowing it would be quite problematic, because the language constructs used in pre-C++11 loops are still useful elsewhere. The old `for` syntax is useful for things like looping over numbers:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    std::cout << i;
```

Likewise, the `begin()` and `end()` methods return iterators which can be e.g. passed to standard algorithms in `<algorithm>`.

Really, the C++ committee doesn't have any reasonable way to prevent old-style loops without also removing useful features in the language or making really weird special cases (like disallowing `begin()` or `end()` from being called in a `for` statement). They don't have any reason to do that, either.

The other cases are similar: there are multiple ways to do the same thing because that's just how language features interact, and there is no reason to attempt to prevent that situation.

Comment: Nice answer, but I would add that if iterators are required for manipulation or can be invalidated by operations in the loop body, a range-`for` almost certainly won't cut it. This is probably the key reason that, as you briefly indicated, the 'old' method of looping still has very valid use-cases for less simplistic loops.