# Is there any advantage of using a range for loop rather than an iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator

```
for (auto& i : just_a_vec )
```

Or an iterator for loop.

```
for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = just_a_vec.begin(); it < just_a_vec.end(); it++)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use iterators instead of array indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131241/why-use-iterators-instead-of-array-indices)

Comment: @Philipp A range-based `for` is syntactic sugar on top of iterators, there is no such performance caveat.

Comment: What ever is most readable and invites fewest mistakes.

Comment: And deviate from the easiest to read/hardest to get wrong only if profiling shows that it's a significant bottleneck.

Comment: look to `std::for_each()` also. supports parallelization where these two do not.

Comment: The range-based for loop has undefined behaviour if the loop body invalidates the containers iterators AND that cannot be corrected in the loop body since there is no access to any of the container's iterators.  Such cases can be corrected in the second form (e.g. after an operation that invalidates `it`, set `it` to be a valid iterator) - albeit still has undefined behaviour if iterators are used after being invalidated.  There are numerous questions here about cases where using a vector's `erase()` member function in a range-based for loop produces unexpected results.

Comment: Some similar questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578219/range-based-for-loop-vs-regular-iterator-for-loop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578219/range-based-for-loop-vs-regular-iterator-for-loop maybe can be merged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterators predate range-based `for` loops, so they used to be the only of these two alternatives available. Nowadays, range-based `for` has mostly replaced iterators when dealing with a simple loop.

However, iterators can be used in various other contexts as well. For example, you can do `std::sort(v.begin(), std::next(v.begin(), 5))` to sort  the first five elements of a vector while leaving the rest of it alone.

Going back to iterating over a whole container:

- If you can accomplish what you want with a range-based for, then it leads to more legible code, so they are preferable by default.
- If you need iterators for some reason, such as using an algorithm that requires them, or because you need to jump ahead or back while iterating, then use those instead.

Also: In the later case, you can/should still use `auto` when declaring the iterator:

```
for(auto it = just_a_vec.begin(); it < just_a_vec.end(); it++) {
}
```

**Edit:** as asked: here's a simple, if a bit contrived, example where an iterator-based loop can still be useful:

```
// adds all values in the vector, but skips over twos values when encountering a 0
// e.g.: {1,2,0,4,5,2} => 5
int my_weird_accum(const std::vector<int>& data) {
  int result = 0; 
 
  for(auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it) {
    auto v = *it;
    result += v;

    if(v == 0) {
      // skip over the next two
      assert(std::distance(it, data.end()) > 2);
      std::advance(it, 2);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh alright then, could you give me some cases when an iterator could be used?

Comment: @apetrai I've updated the answer with an example.

Answer (score 2):

Quick personal answer: Its somewhat sylistic and based on what version of c++ you are using. I typically prefer range based, but there are certainly moments iterators shine as well. Add both to your toolchest. For further reading.

Here is a list of other SO answers that get more into the performance and use cases.

- [What's the difference between iterator syntax in range-based loops for STL containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349520/whats-the-difference-between-iterator-syntax-in-range-based-loops-for-stl-conta)
- [Is the ranged based for loop beneficial to performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821756/is-the-ranged-based-for-loop-beneficial-to-performance)
- [range based for loop vs regular iterator for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578219/range-based-for-loop-vs-regular-iterator-for-loop)

For further information. Google

> Range vs iterator loop c++

Comment: Yes this is very helpful! I also heard that it helps with unorderd maps? Or something like that.